# update db per field from form with multiple inputtypes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, onchange

I have a dynamic form that lists items - with multiple columns per row.
Until now, when the admin clicked the submit button, I did an `serialize()` on the whole form plus AJAX post and PHP then looked up the difference between the database and the form-data. As this seems very not "state-of-the-art", I decided to recode a function using jQuery to only update the changed field. Used input types in the form are mostly `text` type but also `select`.
However, the code so far seems to work. But I want only to show up the changed objects, not the whole form with all it's fields. With the code below exactly thats what happens. As soon as I change the `input text` field, the whole form with all it's columns get POSTed. I also tried to add `onchange="test()"` to each item, but that also didn't seem to do the trick. Anyone ?

#### jQuery

```
function test() {
    var y = $(this).serialize();

    console.log(y);

    $.post("change.php", y, function(data) {
        $("#demo").text(data);
    });
}
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select multiple name="00001[category][]">
                <option value="1">Cat1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Cat2</option>
                <option value="3">Cat3</option>
                <option value="4">Cat4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="00001[description]" value="Descr1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select multiple name="00002[category][]">
                <option value="1">Cat1</option>
                <option value="2">Cat2</option>
                <option value="3">Cat3</option>
                <option value="4" selected>Cat4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="00002[description]" value="Descr2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<pre><p id="demo"></p></pre>
```

#### change.php

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the submit button you could add event listeners to each input and then when they change post the input name and value instead of using serialize. If you want to keep the submit button you could have the event listeners add a class or attribute to the input (or select, textarea etc) and then select based off of that before posting.

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what I want. On the new form the submit button is already removed as you can see from in my code posted above. But the `onchange` event on each input does not seem to work properly. Maybe it's because `serialize()` is not working ?!

Comment: I'm not a jquery expert but I imagine serialize realizes you're within a form and is going to grab everything in the form. I would just use plain javascript to set y to name=value and then just post that.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around a little bit and came to this solution, based on the comments and answers.

```
function test(sel) {
    var x = {};
    var name = $(sel).attr("name");
    var value = $(sel).val();
    x[name] = value;

    console.log($.param(x));

    $.post("change.php", $.param(x), function(data) {
        $("#demo").text(data);
    });
}
```

Which gives the desired associative POST array output in PHP.